# JET ODBC SQL in excel, Case statements vs iif

Tags: sql, excel

I am getting unrecognized keyword when when I am running a query to join two of my sheets in excel.

```
Error - 2147467259 - Unrecognized keyword WHEN
```

This error is due to case statements, they are not accepted in JET ODBC.
 I am using JET ODBC and querying within excel sheets.

Can anyone help write a proper case statement using JET ODBC syntax, i can't get this to work.

```
iif ([stack$].[business_name] = 'GELP' 
AND [overflow$].[level] = 'Package' THEN [overflow$].[identifier1]) END AS standardized_identifier,
```

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code!

Comment: Posting the sql query would help a lot...

Comment: im getting to it!

Comment: Post an error, code, sql, anything will help.

Comment: can this be reopened?

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` statements are not supported in SQL when hitting Excel sheets. You are using the JET ODBC/OLEDB provider in Windows which has limited syntax.

Instead use the [IIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) function which is similar syntax to Excel's `If()`.

As an example, your first `CASE` would look like:

```
iif([stack$].[managementl6description] = 'GLOBAL EQUITY-LINKED PRODUCTS', 'GELP' , iif([stack$].[managementl6description] = 'EQUITY MARKETS', 'EQUITY MARKETS', iif([stack$].[managementl6description] = 'FOREIGN EXCHANGE', 'FIC Foreign Exchange', NULL))) AS business_name
```

Comment: is `iif` just used to replace `case` ?  I am getting a new error `method 'Execute; of object' _ Connection ' failed`

Comment: Not sure on that one. Would probably have to see more code. It could be your connection string? At any case, I think it's worthy of a new question. Just make sure you add your code before hitting the submit button. Folks are quick to downvote and close if there isn't enough information to answer.

Comment: do you know any documentation for JET ODBC? I just cant get the case/iif statement to work.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's the engine under MS Access though, so if the code works in Access, it will work in Jet. Access also doesn't support CASE statements.